# Textmate Tab browsing

Tags: textmate

Something that I have always wanted in TextMate was a different way to open files.

For instance, when I open a file in TextMate, I would love the active tab to default in position 1. Then when I open another tab, that tab should take over position 1, and the rest will shuffle down the list.

Are there any plugins for TextMate that provide this type of functionality?

Comment: So you want to reverse the order in which tabs are opened?

Comment: Correct. And if I focus on any of the tabs, it would come to the 1st index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe such a plugin exists.

There are two plugins providing supercharged alternatives to the project drawer:

- [MissingDrawer](https://github.com/jezdez/textmate-missingdrawer)
- [ProjectPlus](https://github.com/ciaran/projectplus)

They don't provide the feature you want but you could try to get in touch with their authors to see if they can add it or point you in the right direction.

The ProjectPlus project has been pretty much dead for years (there are unanswered pull requests from january/february 2011) but there seems to be some action on MissingDrawer.

If you know Objective C you may be able to hack something from their sources.

Whatever the outcome it may work for the "click on a file in the drawer" way of opening a file but not for other ways.

Did you look at TextMate's .plist? I've heard there are some hidden gems there.