# look at files quickly in Textmate without opening them in a new tab?

Tags: textmate

So I'm brand new to TextMate. I use the file drawer on the side for my whole rails app. But I find my self clicking through a bunch of files before I find the one I'm looking for, or piece of code I'm looking for. This causes every file I've looked at to open in a new tab. Before long I have 25 tabs open, which completely defeats the purpose of tabs in the first place.

Is there a way to make it so that you can look at a file and have it not open a new tab? Then I could have tabs for the 1 or 2 files I'm working with, and still poke around the others at will.

Comment: [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7824274/textmate-tab-browsing)

Answer (score 0):

There have been plugins written for TextMate over the years that add a Quick Look feature to the file pane, like Quick Look in the OS X Finder.

Here's one recently-made plugin that that you could try: https://github.com/belkadan/textmate-quicklook